# Changing Legend in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Here is an example dataframe:

```
Tag/Percentage/type
A   0,3         1
E   0,4         1
F   0,5         2
F   0,6         2
G   0,5         3
T   0,2         3
H   0,1         4
```

I'm trying to plot the tag (x-axis) against the Percentage (y-axis) and make different point shapes represent the different types.

Additionally, I want to rename the types to TLA1, TLA2 etc. and I want to do it in `ggplot()` because I have some other dataframes that I need to plot. For the sake of simplicity, I want to be able to copy the code and reuse it.

However, I can't manage to combine all these things into one `ggplot()`.

Code:

```
ggplot(MeMeT1A, aes(x = tag, y = Percentage, fill = type)) +
  geom_point(size = 3)+
  labs(title="Top5 Medulla Input Types", x="Inputneuron", y="(%) medulla input")+
  scale_fill_manual( name="Experimental\nCondition",
                    breaks=c("1", "2", "3","4"),
                    values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9","#E69F00"),
                    labels=c("Control", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2","Lol"))+
    scale_shape_manual(name="Experimental\nCondition",values=c(15, 16, 17,18))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1), linetype = "longdash", color = "gray")+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 8), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

With this code I get the following plot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkhFg.png)

I only want to add colors for the different tick labels and change their shape.

Comment: Add `shape = type` inside `aes()`. And to color your points switch to `color` instead of `fill`, i.e. use `color = type` and `scale_color_manual`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to generate different coloured points, use `color` rather than `fill` in the aesthetic.  Also, if you're trying to change the point shape, you'll also need to define the `shape` aesthetic as a function of `type`.  Also, `type` should be a factor, though I just used `as.factor()` in the call to `ggplot()`.   You can then set the attributes of the color and shape aesthetics with `scale_*_manual()`.  To ensure that both attributes show up in the same legend, they'll need to have the same names and labels, though the values will be different because they are controlling different aspects of the point.

```r
library(ggplot2)
tab <- read.table(textConnection("tag Percentage  type
A   0.3         1
E   0.4         1
F   0.5         2
F   0.6         2
G   0.5         3
T   0.2         3
H   0.1         4"), header=TRUE)

ggplot(tab, aes(x = tag, y = Percentage, color = as.factor(type), shape=as.factor(type))) +
  geom_point(size = 3)+
  labs(title="Top5 Medulla Input Types", x="Inputneuron", y="(%) medulla input")+
  scale_color_manual( name="Experimental\nCondition",
                     values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9","#E69F00"),
                     labels=c("Control", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2","Lol"))+
  scale_shape_manual(name="Experimental\nCondition",
                     values=c(15, 16, 17,18), 
                     labels=c("Control", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2","Lol"))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0, 1, by = 0.1), linetype = "longdash", color = "gray")+
  theme(text = element_text(size = 8), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know that! Thank you so much for the quick response, now I have my desired plot :).